# List.RemoveAt throws exception on second iteration

Tags: c#, list

I'm porting some old homework from Java to C# and I keep getting an ArgumentOutOfRange exception trying to remove an element from a list. I'm calling a method on an object that in turn calls a static method on the class that contains the list.

I'm looping over an array of Player objects, which copies cards from the DeckOfCards into the player's Hand and remove that card from the DeckOfCards. It works on the first iteration and fails on the second.

Edit: As requested, here is the full code of the files in question.

Runner.cs

```
using System;

public class Runner
{

    public static void Main(String[] args){


       int choice = -1;

        while(choice != 3){
            Console.WriteLine("\nBlackjack!");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 1 to choose the timid strategy.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 2 to choose the aggressive strategy.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press 3 to exit.");

            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            try
            {
                choice = Convert.ToInt32(input);
                if ((choice == 1) || (choice == 2))
                {
                    BlackJack game = new BlackJack(choice);
                    game.playRound();
                    /*Console.WriteLine(DeckOfCards.cardCount());
                    DeckOfCards.draw();
                    Console.WriteLine(DeckOfCards.cardCount());
                    DeckOfCards.draw();
                    Console.WriteLine(DeckOfCards.cardCount());
                    Console.WriteLine(DeckOfCards.topCard());*/
                }

                else if (choice == 3)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nThanks for playing!");
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter a number between 1 and 3");
                }
            }
            catch (OverflowException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter a number between 1 and 3");
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nPlease enter a number between 1 and 3");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Blackjack.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class BlackJack {

    private Player[] players;

    /*
     * Passes an integer value to player to determine which strategy the Player object will have.
     * Sets up the DeckOfCards and adds both Player objects to an array.
     * @require integer value 1 or 2
     * @ensure this.players[0] will have a non-null strategy object and both players added to an array 
    */   
    public BlackJack(int choice) {
        DeckOfCards.resetDeck();
        this.players = new Player[2];
        this.players[0] = new Player(choice, "Player"); //player
        this.players[1] = new Player("Dealer"); //dealer
    }

    /*
     * Plays the game, with each player hitting until the hand value specifed by his strategy is reached
     * or his hand value is greater than 21.
     * @require two non-null player objects
     * @ensure Players hit according to the specified strategies or until hand > 21
    */
    public void playRound() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.players.Length; i++) { 
            this.players[i].takeTurn();
            this.players[i].showHand();
            //Console.WriteLine(DeckOfCards.cardCount());
            //DeckOfCards.showDeck();
        }

        //If the player's hand is greater than the dealer's hand and less than or equal to 21
        if(this.players[0].handValue() > this.players[1].handValue() && this.players[0].handValue() <= 21){
            Console.Write("Player wins!");
        }
        //If the player's hand is less than or equal to 21 and the dealer has busted
        else if((this.players[0].handValue() <= 21) && this.players[1].handValue() > 21){
             Console.Write("Player wins!");    
        }
        //Otherwise, the dealer has won.
        else{
             Console.Write("Better luck next time, pal.");
        }

    }

}
```

DeckOfCards.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class DeckOfCards { 

    private static List<Card> deck = new List<Card>();

    private DeckOfCards(){}

    /*
     * Loads the deck with cards programmatically
     * @require
     * @ensure 52 unique cards in a shuffled deck ArrayList
    */
    public static void resetDeck(){
        //instead of having a 52 element array
        String[] suits = {"Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds"};
        String[] faceValues = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "King", "Queen", "Ace"};
        int[] pointValues = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11};

        deck.Clear();

        /*
         * Generates card names and values by looping through two arrays
         * Creates a new Card object and adds it to the deck ArrayList
        */
        for(int i = 0; i < suits.Length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < faceValues.Length; j++){
                String cardName = faceValues[j] + " of " + suits[i];
                deck.Add(new Card(cardName, pointValues[j]));
            }
        }

        shuffle();

    }

    /*
     * Shuffles the deck
     * @require a non-empty deck ArrayList
     * @ensure cards in array appear in a different order
    */
    public static void shuffle()
    {
        var rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        deck = deck.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToList();
    }

    /*
     * Returns the value of the top card and removes it from the deck ArrayList
     * @require deck size > 0
     * @ensure deck size - 1
    */
    public static Card draw() { 
        //This is giving me problems. I think it's happening becuse the draw() method, removes an element from the list, is called in a loop.
        //Apparently C# has problems with removing elements from lists in loops.
        Card result = deck[0];
        deck.RemoveAt(0);
        return result;
    }

//Methods from here till EOF for testing purposes only
    internal static void showDeck()
    {
        foreach(Card c in deck){
            Console.WriteLine(c.getName() + " has value " + c.getValue());
        }
    }

    internal static int cardCount()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach(Card c in deck){
            i = i + 1;
        }
        return i;
    }

    internal static Card topCard()
    {
        return deck[0];
    }

    internal static Card bottomCard()
    {
        return deck[51];
    }

}
```

Player.cs

```
using System;

public class Player {

    private Hand hand;
    private string name;
    private IStrategy myStrategy;

    /*
     * Constructor, sets up the Player object
     * @require integer value 1, 2, or 3, string name
     * @ensure Player with empty hand, specified name and selected strategy
    */
    public Player(int choice, string name){
        this.hand = new Hand();
        this.name = name;

        if(choice == 1){
            this.myStrategy = new TimidStrategy();
        }
        else if(choice == 2){
            this.myStrategy = new AggressiveStrategy();
        }
        else{
            this.myStrategy = new DealerStrategy();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Overloaded, sets up the Player object
     * @require string name
     * @ensure Player with specified name and dealer strategy
    */
    public Player(string name)
    {
        this.hand = new Hand();
        this.name = name;
        this.myStrategy = new DealerStrategy();
    }

    /*
     * Adds a card to the player's hand
     * @require deck > 0 cards
     * @ensure hand + 1 card, deck - 1 card
    */
    public void giveCard()
    {
        hand.addCard(DeckOfCards.draw());
    }

    /*
     * Adds card to the hand until the hand value reaches the limit specified in the stratgy or exceeds 21.
     * Checks for aces in a hand that exceeds 21 and changes them from 11 to 1 point if present.
     * @require non-null hand, deck >= 0 cards
     * @ensure cards added to hand until strategy limit is reached or 21 is exceeded
    */
    public void takeTurn()
    {
        int hitMe = 1;
        while (hitMe == 1)
        {
            giveCard();

            if (hand.getValue() > 21)
            {
                hand.changeAceValue();
            }

            hitMe = this.myStrategy.hitOrStand(hand.getValue());
        }
        /*
         * Note to self: This originally malfunctioned because the hitMe/myStrategy assignment needed to be last, not first.
         * The pieces of this method are all tested separately.
        */
    }

    /*
     * Prints the results of the round
     * @require non-null hand >= 0 cards
     * @ensure hand point value printed to screen
    */
    public void showHand(){
        Console.WriteLine();
        hand.showHand();
        if(hand.getValue() <= 21){
            Console.WriteLine(this.name + " stands at " + hand.getValue());
        }
        else if(hand.getValue() > 21){
           Console.WriteLine("Bust! " + this.name + " is over by: " + (hand.getValue() - 21));
        }
    }

    /*
        * Returns the player's name
        * @require string name != null
        * @ensure returns the player's name
       */
    public string getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }


    //Methods from here till EOF for testing purposes only

    /*
     * Returns the hand's value.
     */
    internal int handValue()
    {
        return hand.getValue();
    }

    /*
     * Deals a card worth one point.
     * Used to test whether a player will stand at the value specified in his strategy.
     */
    internal void standTest()
    {
        int hitMe = 1;
        while (hitMe == 1)
        {
            hand.addCard(new Card("Worth One", 1));
            hitMe = this.myStrategy.hitOrStand(hand.getValue());
        }
    }

    internal int cardCount()
    {
        return this.hand.cardCount();
    }

}
```

Here's the strategy for the dealer, which is the player that is crashing. It's the same as the other two verbatim except the handValue part.

```
using System;
public class DealerStrategy : IStrategy{
    /*
     * Determines whether the player will hit or stand based on the value of his hand.
     * @require integer value >= 0
     * @ensure positive integer result
    */
    public int hitOrStand(int handValue) {
        int result = 1;

        if(handValue >= 17){
            result = 1;
        }
        else if(handValue < 1){
            result = 1;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The code above works for the first iteration of the loop. It throws an exception on the second iteration and Visual Studio tells me that Deck's `Count = 0` and that `result = null`.

And here is the stack trace.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233086
  Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=index
  StackTrace:
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at DeckOfCards.draw()
       at Player.giveCard()
       at Player.takeTurn()
       at BlackJack.playRound()
       at Runner.Main(String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

What am I doing wrong? This was trivial in Java.

Comment: Probably the deck has only one item.

Comment: How do you fill the deck object?

Comment: That was my first thought, but doesn't List get automatically reindexed? Doesn't deck[1] then become deck[0]?

Comment: Something is wrong in code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: For whatever reason, deck contains no Card. Debug the rest of your code...

Comment: Yes, List reorders.  Can we see other uses of the `deck`?  Like what is `DeckOfCards`?

Comment: @Chad Yes, but if the list only had one card then on the second iteration it will be empty.  Most likely the actual issue is in the code that populates the deck.

Comment: Throws exception.. Well, what exception? post the message, stacktrace and name of the exception. Also which line throws it?

Comment: I suspect you'll have a Shuffle() method somewhere, and that isn't populating the `deck` list properly. Please post code showing initialisation of  `deck` and how you add `Card` instances to it.

Comment: Edited @Siriam Sorry about that. I thought I mentioned that in the post. It's an ArgumentOutOfRange exception.

Comment: @Neil I omitted the shuffle() method from the post because I get the same exception even if I remove it from the program all together. I'll edit the post and include it anyway, though

Comment: Which means that somehow your deck only contains one element. When removed the last element, you try to access element 0; which doeesn't exist and thus the exception.

Comment: @Lars It's in BlackJack.cs's constructor before the player objects are initialized. My runner sets up a new Blackjack object before each game is played, and Blackjack's constructor calls resetDeck().

Comment: We really need to see a minimal, but complete, program that demonstrates the problem. There's still nothing wrong in any code we've seen.

Comment: All I can think of then is that something in takeTurn() or showHand() is modifying `deck`. Can you post those too please?

Comment: Also, please post the method in which `deck` is actually instantiated. I suspect it will be in takeTurn() which resets `deck` to an empty list.

Comment: Deck isn't instantiated. The constructor is private and all of the methods are static.

Comment: So what's the declaration of `deck` then? Is it not a static instance of `List<Card>` ? Or is it something that inherits from `List<Card>`

Comment: Deck is the instance of List<Card>.

Comment: So you've got to instantiate an instance of List<Card> and assign it to `deck` _somewhere_, otherwise you'd be getting a null reference exception anywhere you attempt an operation on `deck`. Where do you create that instance?

Comment: This question is about to be closed because the OP is not posting the full code as requested by several members. I think the OP means well, so I'm not going to vote to close as the last vote which will close the question. Now, given the stack trace: `playRound -> takeTurn -> giveCard -> draw` - the only code that isn't posted here is the `takeTurn()` method. I suspect that the culprit will be found there as @Neil Moss has stated and requested the code. Please add the code as requested.

Comment: I am getting ready to post it. Give me a minute.

Comment: I've updated the question with the full text of the classes from the stack trace.

Comment: My guess?  Your hitMe value is always equal to 1, so it keeps looping.  You are running out of cards.

Comment: "//Apparently C# has problems with removing elements from lists in loops." -> lol, I doubt that's the issue. I agree with LarsTech, your Strategy (whose code we don't see...) is probably drawing and drawing forever - you don't appear to check for bust inside a turn, only between them.

Comment: I'd post an image to show you what's happening when it's run, but I don't have the reputation for it. The first player gets his cards and then stands according to his strategy as he should. Then the exception occurs.

Comment: @LarsTech you're absolutely right and I feel very dumb. The mistake was in my stragegy and I was running out of cards. in DealerStrategy.cs I had a 1 where a 0 should have been. The other two strategies were didn't have that mistake.

What should I do with this question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hitOrStand method is always returning 1:

```
public int hitOrStand(int handValue) {
    int result = 1;

    if(handValue >= 17){
        result = 1;
    }
    else if(handValue < 1){
        result = 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Which means in the takeTurn method, the loop will never stop:

```
public void takeTurn()
{
    int hitMe = 1;
    while (hitMe == 1)
    {
        giveCard();

        if (hand.getValue() > 21)
        {
            hand.changeAceValue();
        }

        hitMe = this.myStrategy.hitOrStand(hand.getValue());
    }
    /*
     * Note to self: This originally malfunctioned because the hitMe/myStrategy assignment needed to be last, not first.
     * The pieces of this method are all tested separately.
    */
}
```

I suspect one of the other strategies is being used for `hitOrStand` which is returning the incorrect value as well, otherwise, as posted, this would result in an infinite loop.

Comment: That did it. It was always crashing on the dealer's turn because the DealerStrategy was the only one that never returned 0.